# How does one discover other nodes on the stellar network once your node is launched?

Tags: nodes

I initiated a test node to get a feel for what it is like to open one. The docker command used to inniate this was docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -p "11626:11626" -p "11625:11625" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --testnet. I would like advice on what to do when I launch a node on the pubnet. How can I discover other nodes, and any reading material related to what exactly is happening when a node is launched would be greatly appreciated. I am unfamiliar with docker and most of the technical aspects related to this, but wish to contribute to the stellar network. Attached is the output docker gave. Thank you in advance.[image]